Parading Slave Women bare-breasted for Attracting the highest bidders or buyers
First of all, I would like to thank in advance for answering in the most kindest way. And i apologize for making my questions so big. Just wanted to let you know where i'm coming from.
I have heard that previously during Imam Malik's time, some slave women were walking around or getting out of their homes bare breasted. He had strongly condemned this practice due to his understanding of the Quran/Sunnah as per this narration:

Kitaab Al-Jami‘ of Al-Imam Ibn Abi Zayd Al-Qayrawani Al-Maliki (died
386 AH): He said, "He (i.e. Al-Imam Malik ibn Anas) strongly
disapproved of the behaviour of the slave women of Madinah in going
out uncovered above the lower garment." He said, "I have spoken to the
Sultan about it, but I have not received a reply." He said, "Beat the
slave women if they do that."

I am aware that slave women had a relaxed awrah compared to the free women as per the differing opinions of the various schools of thought due to their work in servile environments and veiling was prohibited as a social status indicator but in case of fitnah or harassment or fear of trouble they are supposed to cover themselves up as free women have to do.
I am also aware that in some point in history, there were practices of slave women being paraded bare breasted for attracting the highest bidders or buyers. Also I understand that a seller can adorn their slave women for attracting buyers similar to how a woman is adorned for marriage.
I understand that Islam humanizes slaves by granting them certain rights, emphasizing their emancipation, and encouraging them to be treated like family members—with dignity, kindness, and respect. Based on my understanding of the commentaries from various schools of thought, even during the inspection process in slave markets at the time of the Prophet and his companions, the environment was supposedly controlled, with minimal exposure encouraged unless absolutely necessary, and only with the genuine intention to buy could you look or touch upto some extent (over clothing in Umar R.A's case), touching prohibited in the presence of lust. (please correct me if i'm wrong).
My Question is as follows:

Was bare chested display for auctions or convenience or parading them bare chested for attracting the highest bidders, is that islamic or buyers islamically sanctioned (haram or
halal)? Or was it just a corrupt practice that the masters used to do
to exploit their slave women for commercial purposes or personal
benefits? If it is halal, why? It spreads fitnah, encourages lustful
intentions,objectifies and exploits slave women, public indecency,
strips off their dignity, violates modesty rules etc which is quite
contrary to inspection which usually happens for practical reasons
out of necessity as opposed to lustful intentions.

Also please answer this as well if possible Question regarding Slave Women Inspection Limits in the marketplace Thanks!

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that these are too many questions for one post you should better stick on one question per post and ask your questions separately or check if some of these are already answered. See also in our meta.

W.Salam. Hi thank you so much for replying! Could you please answer the first question for me? I'm aware you answer questions on this site, and I'd be really grateful to have your insight on it, also i'll take your suggestion and seperate it into multiple questions, thanks!

I''d need to do some research on the topic. But I still strongly suggest you to edit your question(s) and shorten it to one question and consider asking the other questions in (a)  new post(s).

I think you must distinguish between slaves in public or private places and those for sale in a (slave) market. The statement of imam Malik is rather on the slaves in public or private while your question even if it doesn't seem to have a clear focus, rather addresses the topic of selling slaves in a market.

Hi @Medi1Saif, thanks for getting back, i would like to know about all of the points you mentioned, slaves in public (on the streets), infront of non-mahrams, and in slave market places. Also, my question is not about what the people of that time allowed but what is islamically halal and haram. One is slave women hanging out bare breasted on the streets, another is being paraded by their masters for sales. Also i didn't understand what you meant here "The statement of imam Malik is rather on the slaves in public or private"

I only have found some fatwas on the topic, but could hardly find sources for that. It rather seems that especially books on slavery and Islam try to avoid discussing this topic. Maybe because the authors are rather contemporary scholars. So what I knew about is that the ahadith of ibn 'Umar are generally regarded as problematic. Imam Malik was against seeing more of a slave-girl for sale than her hands, some scholars may allow seeing more if there was an intention of buying and there was no risk of lust.... only the hanbalis toke the ahadith as evidence and accepted them without premises.

The topic is often mentioned in different sections of fiqh books it may appear in a section about 'awarh, prayer,clothing ,trading etc.

Thank you for giving me helpful info, but regardless, parading slave women for attracting the bidders, wouldn't it invite lustful gazes and actions, the whole premise of parading in such manner is kind of focused on lust. What are your thoughts on that? Also I'm aware of the different schools of thought, then again, does it mention anywhere that ibn umar looked or touched the slave women bare breasted?

Also as far as i have researched on the different schools, some say hands, neck, back, stomach even chest(said by some scholars not all) is allowed to be inspected , seeing is allowed if there is intention of buying, out of necessity, some consider it makruh tahrimi if there is lust involved (discouraged)(ofcourse not private parts which is navel to knee for slave women) but touching is not allowed if there's lust. And Imam malik allowed touching over their clothes to see face, neck, back and hands by turning them around. Basically he didn't allow much to see without clothes.

Imam Malik was against seeing more of a slave-girl for sale than her hands - true
