Ibn Umar calling slave girl a commodity?
Assalamu Alaikum,
I wanted to know about this narration or athar from
Musanaf ibn Abi Shayba, Volume 4 page 289 Tradition 20240

حدثنا جرير عن منصور عن مجاهد قال كنت مع بن عمر امشي في السوق فإذا نحن
بناس من النخاسين قد اجتمعوا على جارية يقلبونها فلما راوا بن عمر تنحوا
وقالوا بن عمر قد جاء فدنا منها بن عمر فلمس شيئا من جسدها وقال أين
أصحاب هذه الجارية إنما هي سلعة
Jarir narrated from Mansur from Mujahid who said: I was walking with
Ibn Umar in the market when we came across some slave traders gathered
around a girl, inspecting her. When they saw Ibn Umar, they stepped
aside and said, "Ibn Umar has come." Ibn Umar approached her and
touched a part of her body, then asked, "Where are the owners of this
girl? She is merely a commodity."

My Questions are as follows:

Is this narration authentic?
Why does Ibn Umar say things like "She is merely a commodity"? And nobody even asked him what the slave woman was, he had to state that outwardly for no reason, slaves are supposed to be treated like brothers and sisters and they have dignity as well. If you are inspecting them to buy them, buy them and take them home, no need to pass derogatory comments. It leads me to think either the narration is problematic or Ibn Umar is.

Thank you in advance for you kind answer.

Ibn Umar. Not Umar.

There is a difference between Umar and Ibn Umar. The narration is authentic. Ibn Umar says that she is merely a commodity to mean that she can be examined and touched because she is a commodity. It is not derogatory, being a commodity does not negate the recommendation of good treatment. Ibn Umar doesn't sound angry at all to me.

Thank you for correcting me about the difference. However, why state something like that when nobody asked that specifically, The others were inspecting the slave woman as usual, then he had to explicitly call her a commodity for what reason? I mean if somebody had asked him, It would have been understandable. Sorry i am a bit ignorant on this, i apologize in advance.

@UmH I also read most of your answers regarding slavery, could you please kindly look at this question if you have the time? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!
https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/84908/parading-slave-women-bare-breasted-for-attracting-the-highest-bidders-or-buyers

I have already mentioned the reason, to explain that touching her is not an issue. Why should he abstain from saying it just because you seem to have an issue with the term?

Regardless of the term used, the slave traders also knew what the slave woman was, they were already inspecting her, for him to outwardly come and say out of nowhere, "she's merely a commodity" kind of sounds like someone's recording him saying it. Not about abstaining but nobody asked. Just sounds random. Just that. And also the word "merely" is problematic, they were bought and sold and considered properties, fine, but they are not just "merely" commodities. They also have human value.

Possible answer:
Ibn Umar may have referred to the slave woman as "merely a commodity" to emphasize her status within the legal framework of slavery and to discourage any inappropriate emotional attachments or lustful desires from those present. His statement may have been intended to remind the crowd of the transactional nature of the situation and to draw a clear line between her status as a slave and her identity as a human being, thereby reinforcing the moral limits of their behavior.
